# Different Qt window behavior depending on how loadUi is used

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've come across some puzzling behavior in terms of widget resizing when using PyQt4 (and PySide) when using a `.ui` file and loading it with `loadUI`. Consider the following example:

```
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.uic import loadUi

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', self)


class MainTest(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainTest, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def add_widget(self):
        self.layout.addWidget(Widget())


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

main = MainTest()
main.show()
main.add_widget()

app.exec_()
```

where `mywidget.ui` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ScatterWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="ScatterWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>287</width>
    <height>230</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="option_dashboard" native="true">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="xAxisComboBox">
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

If we run this, this produces a window with a combo box, but the combo box always retains the same size when the window is resized:

[image]

However, if I simply change the `loadUI` line to::

```
        self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', None)
        self.setLayout(self.ui.verticalLayout)
```

then the combo widget is resized when resizing the widget:

[image]

Why might this be happening? What is the difference between:

```
        self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', None)
        self.setLayout(self.ui.verticalLayout)
```

and

```
        self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', self)
```

? (Just to clarify, in my case, the desired behavior is the case where the combo box gets resized with the window)

I see the same issue with PySide, so this suggests that this is expected behavior, but can someone explain the difference between the two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is readily answered by the [PyQt4.uic docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module). But to spell it out:

This code:

```
    self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', self)
```

will load the ui *into* the object passed as the second parameter of `loadUi`. So `self.ui` and `self` end up being exactly the same object.

But this code:

```
    self.ui = loadUi('mywidget.ui', None)
```

returns a *new instance* of the ui class (which has no parent).

However, none of this has anything to do with the resizing of the child widgets. The reason this doesn't work as expected, is because, in Qt Designer, you did not set a layout on the top-level widget (i.e. `ScatterWidget`). If you do this, the first example will work correctly.

(Note that setting a layout on the `option_dashboard` widget is not enough - the top-level widget must have its own layout as well).

Comment: Thanks! This does fix it for PyQt4, however, it still doesn't work for PySide: https://gist.github.com/astrofrog/42c43f74b6a09fe54cf2 - do you have any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, pyside's `QUiLoader.load` does not work in the same way as pyqt's `uic.loadUi`. In pyside, the second argument becomes the *parent* of the returned widget. Secondly, there are still some widgets that are lacking layouts: namely, `ScatterWidget` and `Widget`. In general, *every* container widget must have its own layout.